# How to compare corresponding positions in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have N number of list of same length. How can I compare these lists in corresponding position and output the number of positions where they all match?

For example:

```
A=[1,0,1,1]
B=[1,1,1,1]
C=[1,0,1,0]
```

comparison of these three list would output `2` as only position 1 and 3 matches.

I was thinking of converting it into tuple and then zipping it `K=zip(A,B,C)`, then add each tuple to see if it matches the number of list.

The problem almost sounds like I am missing something that is rather trivial, maybe!

Comment: I was thinking of converting it into tuple and then zipping it `K=zip(A,B,C)`, then add each tuple to see if it matches the number of list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> A = [1, 0, 1, 1]
>>> B = [1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> C = [1, 0, 1, 0]
>>> [len(set(i)) == 1 for i in zip(A,B,C)]
[True, False, True, False]

>>> sum(len(set(i))==1 for i in zip(A,B,C))
2
```

Comment: I like using `len(set(i))==1` to do correctly what I botched horribly.

Comment: @Floris, thanks. Happy you didn't take my criticism the wrong way.

Comment: not a bit. You were right to point out that my brain had turned to mush. Unlucky for me it gave the right answer, leading me into a false sense of security. Confirmation bias and all that. Good luck getting to 100k - you are so close now!

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(1 if x == y == z else 0 for x, y, z in zip(A, B, C))
2
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was thinking but couldnt express it in codes :)

Comment: You might want a bit of an explanation of your code here, sometimes comprehension can be a bit hard to understand :)

Comment: @aj8uppal, but then this is a generator expression ;-)

Comment: You can simplify to `sum(x == y == z for x, y, z in zip(A, B, C))`. Which is a fine way to write it if there are only ever 3 lists to be compared

Answer (score 1):

Using `set`, as in gnibbler's answer, works for lists containing any kinds of *immutable* elements -- arbitrary integers, floats, strings, tuples. OP's question doesn't impose any restrictions on what the lists may contain, and assuming only 0 and 1 doesn't simplify anything. The following also works for an arbitrary number of lists, not just 3, which *does* seem to be part of OP's requirements.

```
A=[1,0,1,1, 'cat', 4.5,     'no']
B=[1,1,1,1, 'cat', False,   'no']
C=[1,0,1,0, 16,    'John',  'no']
D=[1,0,0,0, (4,3), 'Sally', 'no']


def number_of_matching_positions(*lists):
    """
    Given lists, a list of lists whose members are all of the same length,
    return the number of positions where all items in member lists are equal.
    """
    return sum([len(set(t)) <= 1 for t in zip(* lists)])

print(number_of_matching_positions(),
      number_of_matching_positions(A),
      number_of_matching_positions(A, A),
      number_of_matching_positions(A, B),
      number_of_matching_positions(A, B, C),
      number_of_matching_positions(A, B, C, D))
```

This will print `0 7 7 5 3 2`.

If the number of lists `N` can be large, performance can be improved by examining as few elements as possible of each tuple from the zip:

```
def all_equal(t):
    """Return True if all elements of the sequence t are equal, False otherwise."""
    # Use a generator comprehension,
    # so that 'all' will stop checking t[i] == t[0] 
    # as soon as it's false for some i.
    return (not t) or \
            all( (t[i] == t[0] for i in range(1, len(t))) )

def number_of_matching_positions_alt(*lists):
    # Instead of 'len(set(t)) <= 1', 
    # do less work in case len(lists) alias len(t) can be large
    return sum( [all_equal(t) for t in zip(* lists)] )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the positions where all the lists are matching then

```
list(x for x, (xa, xb, xc) in enumerate(zip(a, b, c))
     if xa == xb == xc)
```

seems to me the most readable way

If you want to just count the number of columns instead

```
sum(xa == xb == xc for xa, xb, xc in zip(a, b, c))
```

works thanks to the fact that in Python `True` and `False` can be used in computations as if they were `1` and `0`.